# Reading a .txt into a Java graph

Tags: java

So I've got this text file listing movies and actors in them that needs to be set up in a graph in a way that you can connect actors by who was in each movie (example: Josh Brolin->Ian McKellan Josh Brolin was in Hollow Man with Kevin Bacon who  was in Apollo 13 with Tom Hanks who  was in DaVinci Code with Ian McKellen). The problem I'm having is with the way the txt file is formatted.

Apollo13 Kevin Bacon Tom Hanks Gary Sinise
HollowMan Elisabeth Shue Kevin Bacon Josh Brolin
AFewGoodMen Tom Cruise Demi Moore Jack Nicholson Kevin Bacon
OneCrazySummer John Cusack Demi Moore
DaVinciCode Tom Hanks Ian McKellen Audrey Tautou

As you can see, each movie is one word, but each actor is two words. Could anyone help me with reading this into the graph structure? I can't seem to think of a decent way to do it.

Comment: The text file is all in one line? Then there is no chance to do this automatically.

Comment: @Gladdstone Take a look at my solution.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the text didn't format properly. Fixed. I'm having a hard time coming up with a method. the trouble is splitting the line up properly in a way that I get just the movie, then both names of the actor, both names of the next actor, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, each movie is one word, but each actor is two words. Could anyone help me with reading this into the graph structure? I can't seem to think of a decent way to do it

The number of words is not a problem. All you need is it identify a delimiter which won't appear in their names such as a colon `:`.

**Example (to store as txt):**

```
Movie Title1: Actor 1 : Actor 2: Actor 3
Movie Title2: Actor 2 : Actor 4 
Movie Title3: Actor 3 : Actor 5 
Movie Title3: Actor 5

// The first delimited token will always be your movie name, followed by actor names.
```

---

For creating the graph in Java, read the data from the file which can be easily achieved by `String.split(":")` and read them into a data structure of objects.

You can use ***LinkedList*** or simply read them as a ***2D array***:

```
        Movie1    Movie2    Movie3    Movie4
Actor1    O         X         X         X
Actor2    O         O         X         X
Actor3    O         X         O         X 
Actor4    X         O         X         X
Actor5    X         X         O         O
```

You can of course store it as `int` with `0s` and `1s` or 2D array of `boolean` with `true` and `false`. With that, You can get various combinations and relations of the movies and the actors.

For example, to check whether `Actor5` is involved in `Movie2`:

```
return (graph[4][1]);  //Actor5 corresponds to row4, Movie2 to col1
```

Comment: This is a good idea, unfortunately I can't modify the text file.

Comment: @Gladdstone Then is it always the case where Movie names will be single word and Actor names will be double words?

Comment: Yes, the movie will always be a single word followed by at least one actor which will always be two words.

Comment: @Gladdstone Then we have no problem. You can still use a `string.split(" ")`. The first token will be the movie name, and every subsequent 2 tokens will be actor name. With that, everything should be solved right?

Comment: That's what I've been thinking, I run into trouble trying to separate it out. Obviously the movie is substring(0,1), but I need to be able to do this with a variable of actors, so I can't just move on to the next substring.

Comment: @Gladdstone `substring`? If you use `string.split(" ")` it will create an array of string according to the number of words you have dynamically. You don't even have to worry about having an arbitrary number of actors.

Comment: Ah, I see. I read them into a hashmap with the movies as the keys and an ArrayList of actors as the values.. Now I think it should be much easier to create the graph.

Comment: Thanks again. Never actually posted here until now.

Comment: @Gladdstone Glad to help ;)